# AJAX XMLHttpRequest state undefined

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

In the following piece of JavaScript code, i'm executing GetData.php using AJAX. However, when i remove the comments to see the request object's state property, it turns up as undefined, although the PHP script is getting executed properly and my page is changing as i want it to. But i still need the state property. Any clue on what's going on here ?

```
 function refreshPage()
 {
    var curr = document.getElementById('list').value;
    var opts = document.getElementById('list').options;
    for(var i=0;i<opts.length;i++)
     document.getElementById('list').remove(opts[i]);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange=
    function()
    {
        if(request.readyState == 4)
        {
          //alert(request.state);
          //if(request.state == 200)
          {
            fillOptions();
            var exists = checkOption(curr);
            var opts = document.getElementById('list').options;
            if(exists == true)
            {
                for(var i=0;i<opts.length;i++)
                  if(curr == opts[i])
                  {
                    opts[i].selected = true;
                    break;
                  }
            }
            else
            {
                opts[0].selected = true;
            }
            refreshData();
          }
          /*else
          {
             alert(request.responseText);
             //document.close();    
          }*/
       }
    }
    request.open("GET","GetData.php?Address=" + address + "&Port=" + port,true);
    request.send();
 }
```

Comment: Oh btw, refreshData() is a function to update my page and its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean `request.status` not request.state?
Try changing it to the .status and it should work just fine :)

Comment: Umm,i new to AJAX. Is there a difference between the two ? I had read that state/status should be 200 to know that the script executed properly. Which of the two should be checked ?

Comment: I don't think .state is valid, though .status I know is correct. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Ok, i checked with status and its working. I'm getting 200 now. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Excellent :) Mark it as answered so people know it's resolved :)
Welcome to AJAX and Stack Overflow!

Comment: Definitely..but after 4 minutes, coz thats what its showing..!!